# Using silent notification to open a closed app

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any way I can use silent notification to open my application when it's closed? (close in background or force shutdown)

I'm currently using **GCM** with Amazon SNS to handle the notification on my application when it's running.

Comment: GCM will indeed wake a specific `BroadcastReceiver` of your choice, from which you could start your app's main activity.

Comment: Where do I implements that BroadcastReceiver? If my app is closed, it won't be registered to any Activity. Thus, won't be shown no?

Comment: If you register the receiver in your AndroidManifest (create a class that extends it, then add in your android manifest) your app can be notified even when closed

Comment: Check this example: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/

Comment: @LucasCrawford That answered my question, if you want to post your official answer so I can accept it...

Comment: Done. Glad I could help @Jaythaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register the receiver in your AndroidManifest (create a class that extends it, then add in your android manifest) your app can be notified even when closed

Check this example: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/

Glad to help :)